# How can I retrieve in javascript the index of the first character of a string repeatedly in a text?

Tags: javascript

i must obtain in javascript the first index of the term "Query Response" that appears multiple times in "output_pacs" that is a variable in which is allocated the content, that is a file with multiple rows and columns.

```
var strutturaIndici=[];
for(var i=0;i< output.length;i++)
{
    var indice_primo_carattere= output(i).indexOf("Query Response");
    strutturaIndici.push(indice_primo_carattere);
}

logger.debug('StrutturaIndici:' +strutturaIndici);
```

The problem is that the term "Query Response" appears to me multiple times in this file, and i must obtain the first index of this term every time that it appears in this content
with this code, in the console, i don't obtain the indexes, what can i do?
in the console i obtain this:

```
[2021-01-30 12:53:20,002]  DEBUG  (js-connector:?): StrutturaIndici:
```

Comment: `output_pacs` looks like it's an array, so you should be using `[i]` on it and not `(i)`

Comment: Is the problem that `strutturaIndici` ends up as an empty after your loop? Is your loop actually running at all?  What is not working with your current code? What does `output_pacs` look like? Can you please add these details to your question

Comment: Ok, but I don't see anything in the logs that relate to the question. If it's empty, then `output_pacs.length` must be giving you `0`. You need to ensure `output_pacs` has elements in it (assuming it is an array, you haven't clarified this detail yet)

Answer (score 0):

Just make a loop and call `indexOf` everytime with the `lastIndex` as a start to search for next term. And if `indexOf` returns -1, then break out of the loop.

You may look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), how the `indexOf` function is defined on strings

```js
var output_pacs = "test Query Response Query Response hello Query Response"
var indices = [];
var lastIndex = 0;

while (true) {
    lastIndex = output_pacs.indexOf("Query Response", lastIndex + 1);

    if (lastIndex === -1) {
        // No more found
        break;
    }

    indices.push(lastIndex);
}

console.log('StrutturaIndici:' + indices);
```

Comment: Just edited the question. Now i understand, what you are trying to achieve! Should be right now

Comment: Edited again with a working testing string. Should be working now! And no.. the three equals arent by mistake. They are used in javascript to check more strict (also check the type of both variables) than with two equals

Comment: Use the substring/substr method on your string object output_pacs to get substrings for example from one index until the next index in the array

Comment: try to move `logger.debug('x:'+x);` into the loop

Comment: Seems like two newline characters mark the end for a block of logs. Try to search for this.

Comment: i would just do `output_pacs.indexOf("\n\n", someIndex)` to search for the next double-newline after `someIndex`

Comment: where do i write it ? with someIndex you intend indeces[i] right?

Comment: i can't understand how to incorporate it in my code?

Comment: i can't understand how to incorporate it in my code?

Comment: With my code snippet you can get the index where the end for the substring is

Comment: i dont know. sorry

Answer (score 0):

**Try Using:**

```js
function getIndexes(searchStr, str) {
    let searchStrLen = searchStr.length;
    if (searchStrLen == 0) {
        return [];
    }
    let startIndex = 0, index, indices = [];
    str = str.toLowerCase();
    searchStr = searchStr.toLowerCase();
    while ((index = str.indexOf(searchStr, startIndex)) > -1) {
        indices.push(index);
        startIndex = index + searchStrLen;
    }
    return indices;
}

let a  = getIndexes("Query Response", "Query Response Happy New Year Query Response Happy Query Response New Year Happy Pongal Query Response New Year");
console.log(a);
```

Comment: What you need to allocate to new variable